# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION when building NDK Samples

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just cloned the project at [GoogleSamples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) then cd to the native-activity dir. I typed:

```
> gradle clean build
```

And I am getting this:

```
Starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''. Working directory: /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/lib/dx.jar com.android.dx.command.Main --dex --verbose --output /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app/build/intermediates/dex/arm7/debug /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app/build/intermediates/classes/arm7/debug
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
processing /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app/build/intermediates/classes/arm7/debug/./com/example/native_activity/BuildConfig.class...
processing /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app/build/intermediates/classes/arm7/debug/./com/example/native_activity/R$attr.class...
processing /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app/build/intermediates/classes/arm7/debug/./com/example/native_activity/R$string.class...
processing /Users/johndifool/Develop/android/native-activity/app/build/intermediates/classes/arm7/debug/./com/example/native_activity/R.class...


UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/example/native_activity/BuildConfig.class


UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/example/native_activity/R$attr.class


UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/example/native_activity/R$string.class


UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processDirectory(ClassPathOpener.java:229)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:158)
  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/example/native_activity/R.class

4 errors; aborting

:app:dexArm7Debug FAILED
:app:dexArm7Debug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.219 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexArm7Debug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.245 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

I have no idea what's going on here. I updated to latest gradle 2.5 which supports 'model' in app script per the project requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the winner is... Java 1.7!

The first line shows that I am using 1.8 on OSX and this apparently breaks the build. For those of you who run into the same issue and because 1.8 is the latest, I just did:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

prior to rebuilding with the `gradle clean build` command

Comment: Thank you so much for explicitly finding it out!